# MySQL - what type use for range ( e.g. 10-20 cm )

Tags: mysql, types

I have database where I need to store range value of length.

Currently I have column '*length*' where data type is `VARCHAR(255)` and input is like this:

`'100-200cm'`  or `'198-400cm'` etc...

But I need to work with those numbers, so I prefer `INT` values.

**Question:** what **data type** should I use for **range of numbers**?

Answer (score 0):

There is no data type for ranges. Instead, create two fields: one for the start of the range, and another for the end of the range.